# Android studio Unable to locate adb in project/module settings

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Using Android Studio Arctic Fox on MacOS Big Sur, I cannot build my project on my emulator. I can start my emulator ok but no app loads. I get the errors below.

**Unable to locate adb in project/module settings. Locations searched:
ADB_PATH_PROPERTY (android.adb.path): ''
Android SDK location from first Android Module in Project: 
Unable to locate adb in project/module settings. Locations searched:
ADB_PATH_PROPERTY (android.adb.path): ''
Android SDK location from first Android Module in Project:**

I can see adb.exe in platform-tools in finder.

My local.properties files has the path:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
```

Myy .zshrc has the right paths:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I have downloaded the Android Emulator SDK Tool, 31.0.3 and Sdk Platform Tools 31.0.3. From the SDK Components setup window, my SDK location is, `/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk`

[image]

Project structure:

[image]

I am using React Native and have the android folder open in Android Studio.

How can I build my app on my emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Open the project path using `terminal` and try to run this commands:

```
export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

and use the same terminal to `run/build` your app